# Jquery tabs & calendar not binding properly

Tags: jquery, calendar, jquery-1.3, tabbed

I'm implementing a page jquery tab toggle that loads content from hidden divs on the page.  on one of the hidden pages i have a calendar popup (part of the jQuery.UI api.  this works find on it's own page but when i add it to a hidden block and then load that block into the visible window i loose the ability for the calendar to pop up correctly.  i've attempted using live without luck - it's worked for other event bound elements on these hidden div pages.

here is a sample of what im doing:

```
$(".tab-toggle").live("click",function() {
  alert("test");
  $(".calendar-class").datepicker({showOn: 'both', buttonImage: 'images/icon-calendar2.gif', buttonImageOnly: false, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2009:2015'});
});
```

the alert fires on each pageload but the calendar isn't being rebound to an event.

```
$(".calendar-class").datepicker({showOn: 'both', buttonImage: 'images/icon-calendar2.gif', buttonImageOnly: false, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2009:2015'});
```

works fine in pages where it immediately loads into the viewable window but stops working when i tab over to another page and then tab back...

Comment: those tabbed contents are already loaded or do you cal them on-demand when changing tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing, but I didn't use the Jquery UI toggle it. Instead I made a basic show/hide.

[It can be seen here](http://hqchannel.com/calendars)

This is the jQuery I used :

```
$("#changeSortCal").click(function(){
    $("#search_choose_cal").hide();
    $(".calendarContainer").slideDown('slow');
});
$(".calendar-close-button").click(function(){
    $(".calendarContainer").hide();
    $("#search_choose_cal").slideDown('slow');
});
```

`.live` or `.bind` should not be needed since the DatePicker is loaded on pageLoad.